# Migrating accounts in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-workspace-for-business, google-workspace

My school is quite annoying in that they want to delete all email accounts once you graduate. Having graduated I now have to move everything from one email to another, but the thing is that email is also linked to many accounts. Thus I downloaded all my Google Data and have it in an archive. However, everything single bloody tutorial on account migration ends with 'now you've downloaded your data into an archive' without actually instructing me how to move it to another account. So if this isn't possible, what are some things I can to make account migration easier as this Google Data thing clearly doesn't work.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130287/186471

Comment: Have you read this help article from Google :[Copy content from your school account to another account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6386856?hl=en)?